# last element of multiple lists

Tags: python, list, slice

I have different lists that i want to get the last character of the last element out of. I currently have this code:

```
happy = True
    pile1=["vapor","Tie"]
    pile2=["stone","he"]
    pile3=["glass","sto"]
    
    piles=pile1,pile2,pile3
    print([pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles])
```

The problem with this code is that it only tells me what the last elements of all the lists final string/element is. I need it to say if there are only unique elements. If there are only unique element True statement should turn false. This also needs to work if one of the lists are suddenly empty. i know the slicing wont work while a list is empty, so what should i do?

What i mean by if all the elements are unique is that my statement that is for this example happy, should go to false. Like this:

```
happy = True
pile1 = ["vapor", "Ti"]
pile2 = ["stone", "he"]
pile3 = ["glass", "stov"]

piles = pile1, pile2, pile3
print([pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles])
```

Output:
['i', 'e', 'v']
Since thare are ONLY unique elements the statement should be made false

```
happy = False
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If there are only unique element True statement should turn false"? Can you provide a clearer example and include your expected output?

Comment: I'll edit it. i get what you're saying

Comment: is the question easier to understand now?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of unique letters versus the number of elements.

```
happy = len(set([pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles])) != len(piles)
```

Comment: This doesnt work if one of the lists are empty, i need that to be in aswell since the lists that are being checked change their values

Comment: so add an if statement?